# web scraper to get all the assignments from all the courses or from only a specific course in google classroom without google api

Tags: bash, curl, google-classroom

I'm trying to download all the assignments from all the courses(or a specific one) in classroom,it doesn't matter the format,without using the google api but only using bash

The first thing that I tried was to simply download the source of the page,but if you're not logged in you'll get

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=classroom&amp;passive=1209600&amp;continue=https://classroom.google.com/&amp;followup=https://classroom.google.com/&amp;emr=1">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

then I tried to download it using the cookie that i found by analyzing the network using the developer tools

the command that i typed was :

`curl -b cookie.txt 'https://classroom.google.com/u/0/c/asdasdasdas`

**the results were the same**

then i went to the page,I opened the developer tools and I copied as curl some of the request,and redirected the output to a file,but **the output was always a binary file**

Comment: Too many tags barely connected one to another. What exactly have you tried and what problem occurred?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you say _"binary file_", what does the command `file your_binary_file` says about it?

Comment: @Fravadona I don't know why but now i don't get any binary file